# Split QString from returned line of QFile

Tags: qt, qt4, qstring, qfile

How can i split such text fetched from a file ?

```
USA Florida
Russia Murmansk
Germany Bonn
```

In USA,Florida,Russia,Murmansk ... Each word should be saved in a QString. 
Basically i'm doing this way :

```
QFile df("../MyData/visit.DAT");

    if (!df.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {

        qDebug()<<"Could not open file for reading";
        return;
    }

    QTextStream txStream(&df);
    while (!txStream.atEnd()) {

        QString text = txStream.readLine();
        QStringList splitD = text.split(" ");
        qDebug() << "-"<<splitD;
    }

    dataFile.close();
```

When i try to get value from QStringList with `.value(index)` i get same line with both words.
How to split these words in correct way ??

Comment: I don't understand the problem. split() is the correct approach. What's does "i get same line with both words" exactly mean?

Comment: i get : USA Florida line ; but not USA and then Florida

Comment: Your `QStringList` is `splitD` but you are trying to print out a variable called `splitData`. Is this a typo. in your question? If so then please make sure that the code you are showing still shows the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You put the entire List "splitData" to qDebug. This contains two items "USA" and "Florida". Your code most probably works the way you desire, but you are misinterpreting the output.
Try:

```
qDebug() << splitData.at(0);
qDebug() << splitData.at(1);
```

This should give you two lines:

```
USA
Florida
```

Comment: i get crash . at output i have (for first qDebug): USA Florida, and then app crashes

Comment: Strange, could character encoding be the cause? Can you try text.toLatin1().split()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator » or you can split. The operator » can also be concatenated. So you can do something like:

```
QString country, city;
txStream » country » city;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out , by passing tab character in split method, so in `QStringList` will be returned two words from line, accesing them without crashing app.

```
  QTextStream txStream(&df);
    while (!txStream.atEnd()) {

        QString text = txStream.readLine();
        QStringList splitD = text.split("\t");

        if (i%2==0) {

            qDebug() << "Country : "<<splitD.at(0);
            i++;

        } else {

           qDebug() << "City : "<<splitD.at(1);
            i++;
        }
    }
```